# CPU utilization for ECS in Cloudwatch is different from docker stats

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I noticed today that the cloudwatch metric AWS/ECS "CPUUtilization" is reporting values different from what i have when i do docker stat command in the container instance.

For example today in Cloudwatch, the CPU utilization is between 0 and 10% while when i executed docker stat on the container i saw multiple time CPU 100% for the same period.

Why this difference ?

BTW, i'm using a t3.2xlarge instance type.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert by far, but container CPU can either be a function of the allocated CPU OR the total CPU. For instance, if the container is forced to only use 1 core and the machine has 64 cores, the CPU can be at 100% but the CPU of the machine is at 1/64%